# Toggle Required Multiple Taps to Work in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a List in SwiftUI, which displays books. Each book has a isFinished property. When the user taps on the book, it takes them to the detail page where they can toggle the isFinished status. The problem, I am facing is that on the BookDetailView, when the user taps on the Toggle it does not change the toggle status on the first tap. I can tap twice to change the Toggle from off to on etc.

Here is my complete code:

```
struct Book: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var isFinished: Bool = true
}

struct BookCellView: View {
    
    let book: Book
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(book.name)
            Text(book.isFinished ? "Finished": "Not finished")
        }
    }
}

struct BookDetailView: View {
    
    @Binding var book: Book
    @State private var isOn: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(book.name)
            Toggle(isOn: $book.isFinished) {
                Text("Finished")
            }.fixedSize()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var books = [Book(name: "Harry Potter"), Book(name: "Peek Performance"), Book(name: "Ready Player One")]
    
    func bookBinding(id: UUID) -> Binding<Book> {
        
        let index = books.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id })!
        
        return Binding {
            return books[index]
        } set: {
            books[index] = $0
        }

    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(books) { book in
                
                NavigationLink(value: book) {
                    BookCellView(book: book)
                }
            }.navigationDestination(for: Book.self) { book in
                BookDetailView(book: bookBinding(id: book.id))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

**UPDATE 1:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var books = [Book(name: "Harry Potter"), Book(name: "Peek Performance"), Book(name: "Ready Player One")]
    
    /*
    func bookBinding(id: UUID) -> Binding<Book> {
        
        let index = books.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id })!
        
        return Binding {
            return books[index]
        } set: {
            books[index] = $0
        }

    } */
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(books) { book in
                
                NavigationLink(value: book.id) {
                    BookCellView(book: book)
                }
            }.navigationDestination(for: UUID.self) { id in
                let index = books.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id })!
                BookDetailView(book: $books[index])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should watch Demystify SwiftUI from one of the WWDCs. Why have that function?

Comment: I have already watched it multiple times. Any recommendations on what could be the issue.

Comment: Get rid of that function, use the methodologies that are built in.

Comment: I just updated the code. But I am still having the same issue.

Comment: You can copy and run the whole code if you want. That will give you an idea of the problem.

Comment: Like I said before that function that duct tapes a binding has to go, all you did was move it down, really watch that video. Do you see apple using `Binding` in any of the samples for `navigationDestination`?

Comment: Yes they were using binding in one of the sample app. All I want to do is to update the isFinished from BookDetailView. You can copy the code and post a solution, I would love to see your solution.

Comment: Unbelievable! The issue was with Xcode Previews. When I ran it on simulator, it worked fine. Thanks for your help! Lesson learned.

Comment: Just tested my code and it works correctly in the simulator.